# Android application spontaneously crashes

Tags: android

I have an android application that I have recently finished. So I have successfully finished each function and ensured that no errors are encountered.

When I have exported it to an apk file. It runs smoothly. It uses httpRequests to communicate with a remote mySQL server. But there are times that it spontaneously crashes?

For example, I have an activity that would receive input from the user then communicate with the server. It runs smoothly and quickly. But on next run it would crash. And when I restart the application it would run smoothly again even on the second run. I'm just going crazy from this. Are there any explanations for these?

Comment: "But there are times that it spontaneously crashes?" - Bug or bugs in your code...

Comment: try using ACRA to have your stacktraces sent to you, and then you can go ahead and add those to your question.

Comment: A crash should show up as an exception trace in the logs, which you can view in Eclipse or via `adb logcat`.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to debugging your problem is to get a stack trace. If you can reproduce this on your own device, then right after you see a crash, connect it to your dev pc and run this command:

```
adb logcat > crash.log
```

Open the log file, copy and paste its contents on http://pastebin.com/ or similar and add the link to your question. Once we have that, we can try to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) to collect crash reports from your app. You don't need your own server, just a Google Docs form. The integration is described here:
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup#wiki-Setting-up_your_project

The advantage of using a crash report tool vs. logcat is that you don't need physical access to the device. There are also chances that you see crashes that you or your testers didn't even notice.